# Time complexity of Nested loop with dependent variable and logarithmic increment

Tags: java, for-loop, time-complexity, logarithm

what is the time complexity of this loop,
`O(N)` or `O(N (logN ))`

also can you explain how you deduced

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n;  i *= 2) {   
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        // Statement(s) that take(s) constant time
   }
}
```

i have an explanation but it feels wrong

[image: explanation on educative.io]

Comment: Which part of the explanation feels wrong?

Comment: `O(N (logN ))` means _O(n * log(n))_, but the explanation says that it is _O(n + log(n))_. Multiplying and adding is not the same, so why would you think that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused because of the statement `O(n + log(n))`, as you thought that the outer loop runs `logN` times and inner loop runs `N` times so the answer should be `O(NlogN)`. You are wrong here because the inner loop doesn't run `N` times, it only runs `i` times as explained. Now when you sum all the `i` over outer loop, you will get that `2*2^k - 1` statement. This will come out to be order of `N` as given in the explanation.

Comment: **Thanks :)**                                                                            .